# Org-mode COMMENT blocks local variable eval?

Tags: org-mode, file-local-variables

The code below is an org-mode file that will not load `by-backend`. But if I put the org code block `setup` anywhere else besides under `* COMMENT` it does run and `(fbound 'by-backend)` gives `t`. What is it about `COMMENT` that blocks local variable from doing `setup` upon loading the org file? I'm in org-mode 9.0.2 from elpa and Emacs 25.1.1.

```
* COMMENT
  #+name: setup
  #+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent :exports none
  ;; (setq org-babel-latex-htlatex "htlatex")
  (defmacro by-backend (&rest body)
    `(case (if (boundp 'backend) (org-export-backend-name backend) nil) ,@body))
  #+end_src

  # Local variables:
  # eval: (org-sbe "setup")
  # End:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A section with a `COMMENT` keyword is just that, a comment, not to be evaluated.  So speaks the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Comment-lines.html)

> Finally, a ‘COMMENT’ keyword at the beginning of an entry, but after
>   any other keyword or priority cookie, comments out the entire subtree.
>   In this case, the subtree is not exported and **no code block within it
>   is executed either**. [emphasis mine]

If what you want is to have the setup code evaluated, but not exported you can use the `noexport` tag, thusly:

```
* Setup                         :noexport:
  #+name: setup
  #+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent :exports none
  ;; (setq org-babel-latex-htlatex "htlatex")
  (defmacro by-backend (&rest body)
    `(case (if (boundp 'backend) (org-export-backend-name backend) nil) ,@body))
  #+end_src

  # Local variables:
  # eval: (org-sbe "setup")
  # End:
```

`org-sbe` is still able to find the `setup` block, but the entire section, including the source block and its results, will be excluded from export.